# Magento "Remind passowrd" email template issue

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, email, email-templates

By default, when you change a user password from backend using  **Send Auto-Generated Password** a email is automatically send to the user with the new password.
In the **Transactional Emails** area, for this email we have the template called **"Remind Password"**.

I have created a new template based on this one, and i want to add a new variable.

Does anyone know where i can find the PHP files that insert variables in this email template?

Comment: magentoroot/app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php in this check function sendPasswordResetConfirmationEmail and _sendEmailTemplate in that you can see $mailer->setTemplateParams($templateParams);